# adduser_process.php not adding information to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a user creation form on my site that is failing to add any new user data to the relevant MySQL table. I'm really not too sure why it's not adding the data, and it's not throwing any errors that would tell me what's going wrong.

I currently have the following user creation form:

```
<form name="adduser_form" action="process/adduser_process.php" method="post">
    Username:<input id="username" type="test" name="username" />
    Email:<input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    Password:<input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
    <input id="add_usr" type="button" value="Add User" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" />
</form>
```

On clicking the "Add User" button, the formhash JS creates a hashed password, and then submits the form to adduser_process.php:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    var p = document.createElement("input");
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
    password.value = "";
    form.submit();
}
```

adduser_process.php works as follow (left out  tags intentionally):

```
include '../includes/lgn_connect.php';
include '../includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start(); 

$password = $_POST['p']; 

$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

$password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

if($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt); 

$insert_stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Are $username and $email getting set?

Comment: No. No there were not. I feel quite ashamed at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

First mistake is you have settted type as `test` not `text` for username

```
<input id="username" type="test" name="username" />     //should be
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" />
```

the second mistake is with if condition, you have not added extra `()` in condition

```
if($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))   //should be

if(($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")))
```

third mistake is `sec_session_start();` is not function for starting session it should be

```
session_start();
```

Comment: The sec_session_start() is a custom function that I've defined in functions php, partly stolen off random net people and partly my own stuff, that's far more sensible/secure than simply using session_start(), so that's not a mistake. The others... are mistakes, and shall be fixed promptly.